# RHEL7 import tkinter failed inside virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, virtualenv, rhel

On Redhat 7 and python3.6

I can import tkinter without any error:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jul 25 2018, 21:22:33)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>>
```

Within a fresh virtualenv

```
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jul 20 2018, 12:22:32)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/ocr1/CRNN_Tensorflow/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
>>>
```

P.S. It's an entire new virtualenv, created by `virtualenv <name_of_env>` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out two different ways to solve my problem eventually.

**1. Make sure the virtualenv created is using the same python version**

From my case above, the python of virtualenv version is Python 3.6.4, but the python version of my machine is actually Python 3.6.5.

Hence, `virtualenv <name_of_env>` is created with the `lib` of Python 3.6.4. To solve this issue can use

`virtualenv -p <PYTHON_EXE>, --python=PYTHON_EXE <name_of_env>`

or

`virtualenv --python=<PYTHON_EXE> <name_of_env>`

to specify the python exe location.

And use the option `--system-site-packages` to include system modules. (credit to Rob T. answer above)

**2. Copy the package you need from `lib` directly**

This method actually is a bit tricky. Just go the machine python `lib` directory and copy the package you need into virtualenv python `lib` directory

e.g.:

`cd /usr/lib/python3.6.5`

`cp -a ./tkinter /my_project/venv/lib/`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a virtual environment, you start with a "clean" Python environment with none of the system packages. This is what helps make virtual environments isolated, stable, and reproducible.

You have two choices:

1. Install tkinter and any other dependencies in the virtual environment with `pip install`.
2. Use the option `--system-site-packages` when creating the virtual environment to include system modules.

The 2nd option is easier, since you don't need to reinstall anything.  However, the first option is preferred especially when you use `requirements.txt` and `pip freeze`. Then you can easily recreate that virtual environment on another system.

There are some tips that may help you in [How to install Python 3, venv, virtualenv, and pipenv on RHEL](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rob. However, tkinter is included with all standard Python distributions. So you cannot `pip install` tkinter with pip.